# Unable to see calculated table in report view, in my power bi report page

Tags: powerbi

can someone please assist, i can see my calculated table when i switch to Model view, but on the report view, i cannot see the same calculated table. i dont know if i am missing anything. any help will be appreicated, thanks

I compared my dataset and report to others that will currently use, i couldnt trace any difference. what i am expecting to see is that when i switch between my model views and report views, i am able to see the calculated tables i have created (not just in the model view alone)

thanks for any helpful feedback in advance!